# Setting Column Background in WPF ListView/Gridview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview, styles

I'm looking to set the background of a column in a WPF GridView. Many Google results have pointed towards setting the GridViewColumn.CellTemplate to change the appearance of a column. However, I'm met with an issue when setting the background color; it's not stretching to fill the cell:

[image: Ugly Grid View]

Here's the xaml I'm working with:

```
<Window x:Class="ScratchPadWpf.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Window1" Width="300" Height="300">
  <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Red">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Yellow">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the xaml.cs for good measure:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
  public Window1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new[]
    {
      new {FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Bob"},
      new {FirstName = "Frank", LastName = "Smith"},
      new {FirstName = "Tooth", LastName = "Paste"},
    };
  }
}
```

Setting the DataTemplate's Grid's width and height to be larger than the cell with a negative margin can produce a close result, but if you resize the column, the problem shows itself again.

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Height="22" Width="50" Margin="-6">
```

[image: Still Ugly]

Is there a way to fill the cell with color?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That helps in not having to set the width. However, there is still a gap between the two columns. Any way to close that up?

Comment: Alas, the GridViewRowPresenter hard-codes the Margin to 6,0,6,0. I'm afraid it would be a fair amount of work to work around this.

Comment: A hacky workaround is to set the Margin of the containing Grid to -6,0,-6,0.

Comment: I've been trying to solve a similar issue with the column margins - thanks for pointing out the hard-coding.  Now, the question is why?  Guess we'll never know.

Comment: What if you need some columns left aligned and others right? The style is applied to them all.

Comment: @Phil: Use a binding in the style, or a trigger.

Answer (score 5):

Digging up an old thread, but I found a dodgy fix for this

```
<Grid Background="{Binding backGround}" Margin="-6,0,-6,0">
  <TextBlock Margin="6,0,6,0" Text="{Binding myText}" TextAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

Moves the margins so the background color fills the entire cell, but then moves them back so the text is still in the right spot.  Works for now until it's fixed properly.

Comment: Upon digging up this already dug up thread; I'm curious to know if this phenomenon is 'fixed' now?
I'm trying to learn WPF after being away from coding for four years, and can't seem to find any better solutions to creating seamless column backgrounds of differing colours.  Anyone who can point me to a modern/better method is welcome to :D